# botão de play não aparece

Tags: html, css

Olá

Eu coloquei o meu video no HTML mas o video não aparece com botão de play, podem me explicar o que falta colocar para conseguir dar play no video?

```html
<video src="./videos/video2exemplo.mp4" type="video/mp4" width="100%"></video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal é que siga o modelo abaixo, e que tb deixe explicito o atributo `controls` na tag `<video>`

Sua tag `<video>` está formatada "fora dos padrões", pois não tem um `<source>` dentro... talvez seja isso... *(vc até pode colocar o `src` na tag `video`, mas usar um `source` é uma forma mais moderna e vc pode colocar um `fallback`)*

Tente com esse formato abaixo que acredito que vai resolver

```
<video width="100%" controls>
  <source src="./videos/video2exemplo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Funcionou, assim que poder dou o certo.

Comment: @DavidMv valeu a força jovem 

Comment: Conheces algum site onde eu posso conhecer alguns controlos para dar ao video como alterar o volume e ter o play no centro?

Comment: Cara, eu tenho, acho que já conheces o W3schools, eles tem uma quantidade excelente de material ainda mais sobre HTML, aqui está a pagina referente ao assunto:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_controls.asp

Segue também um tutorial em portugues de como usar esses controles:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Comment: @DavidMv acho que o que vc quer é um player customizado de vídeo para não ficar na mão do player nativo do browser né. Existem vários modelos por ai. Aqui no Codepen mesmo tem uma infinidade de modelos prontos https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=video%20player&page=1&order=popularity&depth=everything Mas procure por tutoriais para não ficar na mão dos outros e conseguir fazer o sei do jeito que vc quer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mUW3IqpAtH0. E se quiser aqui tem um plugin https://videojs.com/